# Running Python script to access Django database

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project `myproject`, with an app `myapp`. Now, duppose I have a python script that does something with my Django database (in my case, it creates a CSV file). This script is located at `myapp/make_csv.py`. How do I run this script? If I just type `python make_csv.py` into my command line, I get all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use django functionality - models etc, you need to bootstrap your django. The best way to run a custom script in django is to create a management command - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/